# Jest Vue, test trigger click button, Expected 1, received: 0

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, triggers, jestjs, vuetify.js

I have a problem with unit test to trigger click. Error: Expected: 1, Received: 0
I'm using Vue, Jest and Vue test utils. I wanna test if the button is triggered

Search.vue

```
<v-btn id="searchBtn" @click="searchItem"></v-btn>

methods: {
    searchItem() {}
        ...
    }
```

test.spec.js

```
import Search from '...'

describle(Search, () => {
    it('trigger button', () => {
       const wrapper = shallowMount(Search)

        const clickMethodStub = jest.fn()

        wrapper.setMethods({ searchItem: clickMethodStub })
        wrapper.find('#searchBtn').trigger('click') 

        expect(clickMethodStub.mock.calls.length).toBe(1) 
        })
    })
}
```

Error: 
Expected: 1
Received: 0

Comment: Could you please post ur wrapper.html()?

Answer (score 1):

Because it is vuetify button, you need to use to `shallowMount` to `mount`.

```js
import Search from '...'

describle(Search, () => {
    it('trigger button', () => {
       const wrapper = mount(Search)

        const clickMethodStub = jest.fn()

        wrapper.setMethods({ searchItem: clickMethodStub })
        wrapper.find('#searchBtn').trigger('click') 

        expect(clickMethodStub.mock.calls.length).toBe(1) 
        })
    })
}
```